# Armature Won't Parent to Mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, parent, pose-mode

I am currently trying to add armature to a mesh that I took from the web to repose the body out of a t-pose and into a pose. Every try I've had at clearing the parent and then parenting with automatic weights doesn't seem to actually move the body while the bones correctly move. Any help as to what I'm missing is appreciated.[image: Currently where I am in Blender]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I assume the normals are correct and there is no hole in the mesh since its from the web.

Delete the vertex groups on the mesh and try scaling it up, the automatic weighting works better when the faces are more spread out.